# remove outline from button when clicked

Tags: html, css, button, border, outline

```css
#hamburger-btn :focus :active{
outline: 0 !important;
border: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<button id="test">
  <div id="hamburger-btn">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
</button>
```

I am trying to remove the blue outline from the hamburger btn when clicked however it is not working.  My html is the following:

however it is not working
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A space is a [descendant combinator](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#descendant-combinators), you aren't trying targetting the descendants of the button, you are targetting the button itself.

Remove the descendent combinators from your selector.

---

Also note that to add an OR condition you will need to use a `,` and repeat every part of selector that is shared between the two parts.

---

Also note that the focus is applied to the **button** and *not* to the div inside the button, so you need to target the correct element in the first place.

---

**Danger**: Focus indicators are important accessibility features. Not everybody can or wants to use a mouse. They may *need* to know where the focus is in a document in order to interact with it. Reconsider removing all signs of the focus.

**Do not do this**

---

```css
#test:focus,
#test:active {
  outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<button id="test">
            <div id="hamburger-btn">
            Needs content to be visible
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                 <span></span>
                 <span></span>
            </div>
        </button>
```

Comment: Kudos for **Danger** section!